# Mysql2::Error: Incorrect date value: '--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I moved from sqllite to mysql (recreated the same workspace with mysql right from the beginning. Did not do any migrations).

The code worked well with sqllite but is erroring out with mysql. This is how my database.yml looks like:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: dev
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
```

My code takes in a date through a date select in the view:

```
<%= date_select(:dob, NIL, :use_short_month => true, :start_year => Time.now.year - 100,
                       :end_year => Time.now.year, :order => [:day, :month, :year]) %>
```

The model looks like this:

```
t.string   "firstName"
t.string   "lastName"
t.string   "Email"
t.string   "password"
t.date     "dob"
```

But the insert through the following code in the controller fails:

```
@user.dob = params[:dob]
```

This is the error I get:

```
Mysql2::Error: Incorrect date value: '--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
(1i): '2013'
(2i): '4'
(3i): '18'
' for column 'dob' at row 1: INSERT INTO `users` (`Email`, `created_at`, `dob`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `password`, `personalEmail`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('abc@xyz.com', '2013-04-18 15:46:26', '--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\n(1i): \'2013\'\n(2i): \'4\'\n(3i): \'18\'\n', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 22, NULL, 'ab4d8d2a5f480a137067da17100271cd176607a1', '2013-04-18 15:46:26')
```

I had googled quite an extent but couldnt find any references to this. Appreciate any leads or help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the multiparameter thing. rails date_select helper generates 3 dropdowns which pass 3 different parameters to your controller. if you use mass assignment in your controller, rails magically converts these 3 values to 1 date value. this (quite old) blog post shows a way to do it without mass-assignment: http://www.springenwerk.com/2008/05/set-date-attribute-from-dateselect.html
but, this post is rather old, and there could(!) be a better way by now

Answer (score 0):

Whats clear to me is that the dat object is not formatted correctly for the mysql database. Try something like

```
@user.dob = params[:dob].to_date
```

Try formatting the date object in different ways to see what works. It may also help to open up `rails console` and try working things out manually. Let me know how that goes.

-Brian